# Ukranian character changing to question mark when save from .xlsx to .txt

Tags: excel, csv

I have received an `.xlsx` file with ukranian characters in one of the fields, but when i try to convert to `.csv` or `.txt` the ukranian characters are changing to question marks. Why is this happening?

`.xlsx`:

```
'UAH',  'Колодки тормозные дисковые, комплект' UNION ALL
'UAH',  'Колодки тормозные' UNION ALL
'UAH',  'Колодки тормозные дисковые, комплект' UNION ALL
'UAH',  'Автозапчасть' UNION ALL
'EUR',  'This Is Test' UNION ALL
'EUR',  'This Is Test' UNION ALL
'EUR',  'This Is Test' UNION ALL
'USD',  'This Is Another Test' UNION ALL
'USD',  'This Is Another Test' UNION ALL
'USD',  'This Is Another Test'
```

when saved as `.csv` or `.txt`

```
CURR    DESCC
UAH         ??????? ????????? ????????, ????????
UAH         ??????? ?????????
UAH         ??????? ????????? ????????, ????????
UAH         ????????????
EUR         This Is Test
EUR         This Is Test
EUR         This Is Test
USD         This Is Another Test
USD         This Is Another Test
USD         This Is Another Test
```

Comment: Sounds like an encoding issue to me. Do you save the csv as UTF-8?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Save it as *Unicode Text (*.txt)*. You can then change the name to .csv

PS: I tested this on Office 2010 and it works

[image]

Answer (score 1):

you have to use UTF-8 format when you save in .csv or .txt[image]